# Error: expected END_ARRAY but was STRING - only on specific phones when using mobile internet

Tags: java, android, json, mobile, gson

I have an android application in which I get data from `web services` using `JSON`.

I have tested the application on multiple mobile phones (samsung galaxy s2/s4, htc one/ one s, lg, sony .... ) and the problem I am getting is that when using mobile internet (on wifi everything works fine) on some devices (htc one s, Huawei Ascend p6) I get an `error: expected END_ARRAY but was STRING` and nothing downloads.

I can not wrap my mind why this is only happening on some devices. Did anyone experience anything similar? Please help.

Note: this is using GSON but the same problem happened when I used JSON.

JSON data:

```
[{"ID":"1","name":"Germany"}]
```

class:

```
public class Language {
    @SerializedName("ID")
    public int ID;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
}
```

Code:

```
try
{
    this.httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    this.httpPost = new HttpPost(webserviceURL);
    this.httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this.nameValuePairs));
    this.httpResponse = this.httpClient.execute(this.httpPost);
    this.httpEntity = this.httpResponse.getEntity();
    this.isLanguage = this.httpEntity.getContent();

    if (this.httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(this.isLanguage, "UTF-8");
        Language[] xy = gson.fromJson(reader, Language[].class);
        for (int i=0; i<xy.length; i++)
            Log.i("Language-GSON", "ID: " + xy[i].ID + " - Name: " + xy[i].name);
     }
}catch (Exception e) { Log.i("Language-GSON", "Exception -> " + e.getMessage()); }
finally { this.isLanguage.close(); }
```

Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: expected END_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1

Comment: Can you provide code snippet and the logcat outputs? This question is too vague to be answered specifically

Comment: Code snippet and log provided. Hope you can help.

Comment: At which line is the exception thrown? Can you upload the whole StackTrace if possible

Comment: Exception is thrown in catch. I currently can not get StackTrace because this error only happens on specific phones and it works on mine. I made an apk wich logs into a text file and sent it to the friend that has one of the phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to why it was not working on some phones.

The problem in not in the code and not in the phones or server but in ISP set proxy for the internet provider(default setting). The proxys are blocking php response and so there was no answer. After removing proxy everything worked fine.

The problem now is that some phone have the proxys set and they block response from PHP. That means that my application will not work on mobile data on some phones and I cannot do anything about it.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how could I get around my problem? Or any other way to get data from database that isn't by PHP webservices?

Comment: Have you found any solution ? I have the same problem !

Comment: unfortunately no.. The only this I could do it detect the exception and notify the user to fix their proxy..

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
this.httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
this.httpPost = new HttpPost(webserviceURL);
this.httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this.nameValuePairs));
this.httpResponse = this.httpClient.execute(this.httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Language[] xy = gson.fromJson(response, Language[].class);
for (int i=0; i<xy.length; i++)
{
     Log.i("Language-GSON", "ID: " + xy[i].ID + " - Name: " + xy[i].name);
}
```

I justed testing paring of json with gson locally. It works. If it is not working you will need to check the response form the server. The parsing code is fine.

Also check if the NetworkConnection is available before making a http request. Also check if the response is null or not.

It has nothing to with specific devices or mobile internet. It has something to do with the response from the server.

I am guessing your response is not a valid json. Due check the response by logging the same.

Comment: I will test this but the point is that the code works. It works on every phone if using wifi but when using mobile data there are some phones that throw the exception mentioned before (the phones are: htc one s, huwaei, some lgs) it works on other devices normaly :/

Comment: @user3924685 well its has nothing to do with particular device. Try testing it on htc one s withh mobile data. Log the respone. I am guessing response not being a valid json atleast looking at the error posted. Do null checks also for response

Comment: I have two phones on me right now. HTC ONE S and samsung galaxy s4. Same apk. Both work with wifi. But on mobile data samsung works normaly but htc one s throws: java.lang.IllegalStateException: expected END_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 .

As unlikely as it sound this is what happens..

Comment: I added logging response:

HTC One S: jçUcard16ERROR`HTTP request was interrupted by the host!èFback2

Samsung Galaxy S4: [{"ID":"1","name":"Germany"}]